# How Can I add a USP section in between my Woocommerce Product Catlog After Six Products

Tags: php, woocommerce, product

My goal is to remind customers of Unique Selling Points like "free shipping" while they are browsing the shop.

[image: Example of what I'm looking for to get as a result]

But I can't seem to find the correct call to get in between a row of products.
The only thing I found close to it would be 'woocommerce_before(or after)_shop_loop_item'

My current PHP code displays one USP right above the selected products (4 in this case) and shows up again after 9 products.

```
function display_divs_after_six_products() {
  global $woocommerce_loop;
 if ( is_product_category( array( "propagation-trays", "garden-accessories" ) ) ) { 
  if ( 0 == ( $woocommerce_loop['loop'] - 4 ) % 9 ) {
   echo '<div class="productbreak">';
    echo '<div class="productcontainerfirst">';
      echo '<div class="producticon">';
        // Insert code to display the icon here
        echo '<img src="https://thefarmdream.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Checkmark.png" alt="Checkmark">';
      echo '</div>';
      echo '<div class="producttext">';
        // Insert code to display the text here
        echo '<p><a href="https://thefarmdream.com/packaging-shipping/">Shipping within the <span style="color:#eebb70; font-weight:700;">EU</span></a></p>';
      echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
   echo '</div>';
  }
 }
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item', 'display_divs_after_six_products', 10 );
```

Plus this CSS

```
.productbreak {
    height: 50px;
    overflow: hidden;
    width: 100%;
    padding: 16px;
    font-size: 14px;
    }
    
    .productcontainerfirst {
        overflow: hidden;
        float:right;
    }       
    
    .producticon {
    float: left;
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    }
    
    .producttext {
        display:inline-block;
    }
```

I feel like I'm close but at the same time, I've got a feeling I'm looking in the wrong direction. Maybe someone has an easy fix for my code or a different direction to look in.

I haven't found any on this so far, but would it be possible to break up the existing UL and insert a div in between with the USP and for the UL to continue afterward... just an idea!

Thank you for helping!

Answer (score 0):

My personal solution but in Javascript. Maybe this helps someone else!

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $( document ).ready(function() {
        console.log( "ready!" );
        done = false;
        var j = 8;
        // Get all the li elements in the products list
        let productList = document.querySelectorAll('ul.products li');
        
        // Loop through the li elements
        for (let i = 0; i < productList.length; i++) {
            // Check if the current li element is the 9th in the list
            if (i > 0 && i % j == 0) {
                console.log("dit werkt !");
                // Create a new div element with the class test3
                var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
                newDiv.classList.add('test3');
        
                if (done == false) {
                    // Insert the new div after the current li element
                    productList[i].parentNode.insertBefore(newDiv, productList[i].nextSibling);
                    $('.test3').append( "<div><div><ul><li><img src='https://thefarmdream.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Checkmark.png' alt='Checkmark' /><span>90 days Returns</span></li><li><img src='https://thefarmdream.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Checkmark.png' alt='Checkmark' /><span>Sturdy Seed Trays</span></li><li><img src='https://thefarmdream.com/wp-content/uploads/2022/12/Checkmark.png' alt='Checkmark' /><span>Reviews 4,9/5.0</span></li></ul></div></div>");
                    done = true;
                }
            }
        }
    
    });
</script>
```

With the following CSS ( have it disabled for mobile )

```
<style>
    .test3 {
        width:100%;
        display:inline-table;
        position:relative;
        clear:both;
        height:20px;
        padding: 10px;
    }
    .test3 > div {
        width: 100%;
    }
    .test3 > div > div {
        display: table;
        width: 100%;
        height: 40px; /* for demo only */
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;
        font-size:14px;
    }
    .test3 > div > div > ul {
        padding: 10px;
        display: table-cell;
        text-align: center;
        vertical-align: middle;
        
    }  
    .test3 > div > div > ul > li {
        display: inline-block;
        vertical-align: top;
        margin: 0 auto;
        height: 20px;
        background-color: white;
        padding: 0 20px;
    }
    .test3 img {
        height: 16px;
        margin-right: 5px;
        clear: both;
        float: left;
    }
      
    .test3 span {
        line-height: 1em !important;
        float: left;
    }
      
    .test3 ul:after {
        border-bottom: 1px lightgrey solid;
        width: 100%;
        margin-top: -13px;
    }
      
    @media only screen (max-width:760px) {
        .test3{
            display:none;
        }
    }

</style>
```